# Query SharePoint Online Logs

Tags: powershell, site-template, uls, logs

I created a new site collection in SharePoint Online and then created a subsite. The template I used is Teamsite.
I did nothing else then adding these two elements. No other modifications.
Now I wanted to "Save my site as a template", but I get a "Something went wrong" error message, what tells me the correlation id:

af33759e-306b-0000-18cf-26ae1717e913

I wanted to track the problem with accessing the ULS logs, but the logs on the server seem to be empty:

```
    $uTime=Get-Date
    $utcTime=$uTime.ToUniversalTime()
    $spoTenant= New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant($spoCtx)
    $spoTenantLog=New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.TenantLog($spoCtx)
    $spoLogEntries=$spoTenantLog.GetEntries($utcTime.AddDays(-500),$utcTime,50)
     # $spoLogEntries=$spoTenantLog.GetEntriesByCorrelationId($utcTime.AddDays(-500),$utcTime.AddDays(3), 3, "af33759e-306b-0000-18cf-26ae1717e913")  
    $spoCtx.Load($spoLogEntries)
    $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()
```

This is just a code fragment, that works, but $spoLogEntries is just an empty array in both cases. Connection to SharePoint administration pages works, but neither GetEntriesByCorrelationId nor GetEntries return anything.

Any idea what I could try to track down my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The CSOM classes and the PowerShell commandlets exist but the ability to read ULS log entries has been disabled by SharePoint engineering team since around 2015.

Would suggest that you open a support ticket and request the details of the error. The MS support team has backend access to the logs and will provide you with the details. You dont need to pay additionally for this, it is covered as part of your O365 subscription. You can open a ticket from the Office 365 portal.

Reference to UserVoice  - [Get in SharePoint Online the ULS entries for 'your' correlation id](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/11485845-get-in-sharepoint-online-the-uls-entries-for-your)

Comment: Really?! That’s not built in and you have to open a ticket? That’s lame af

Comment: Yes unfortunately. It used to work till 2015 after which MS engineering disabled it.